# What is this symbol that looks like an L with a number on its lap?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

[What is the symbol used in the denominators?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60NRX.png)

Comment: Tap the link to see the image.

Comment: It looks like a [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Notations), although this very notation is not on the list I linked (closest call being Pringsheim's notation). But this also looks like a power series. Context wouldn't hurt I guess then?

Comment: This is an ancient way to write factorials. It was still used in British manuals at the beginning of the 20th century.

Comment: Oh, you learn new things everyday! Thanks @BernardMasse.

Comment: @BernardMasse I remember reading about this notation in the Princeton Companion to Mathematics. It was a specific entry by Ben Green on the Gamma function.

Comment: And [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#History) agrees: "The notation $n!$ for factorials was introduced by the French mathematician Christian Kramp in 1808. Many other notations have also been used. Another later notation, in which the argument of the factorial was half-enclosed by the left and bottom sides of a box, was popular for some time in Britain and America but fell out of use, perhaps because it is difficult to typeset."

Comment: Correspondingly, you may see (in old books) the subfactorial (=derangement) written using the right and bottom of the enclosing box.